# Why is redis set and get super slow then disk

Tags: python, mysql, memory, redis

I have the following code:

```
arr = {}
for i in range(0, 1000000):
    arr[i] = i*2

redis_client.hmset("data_arr", arr)

g = []
for i in range(0, 100):
    v = redis_client.hget("data_arr", str(random.randint(0, 10000000)))
    if v!=None:
       g.append(v)
```

Firstly, inserting 1 million rows is very slow on redis (greater then 60 seconds) where as simple disk based saving takes less then 1 second.

Secondly, the redis `hget` is super slow, much slow than reading the json dump from disk and processing it using a linear search method.

Please suggest me to speed up redis and alternatives ways where i can store data in ram for a period of time and can access it as API.

I am initially using MySQL on memory for storing temporary data, because MySQL is very good to run search and other SQL transactions but the difficulty increases when i want the data stored to live for a certain amount of time only or delete them when heavy.

Comment: Tried with node.js and writing takes about a second (i7, hdd, localhost). Maybe there is something wrong with your redis setup?

Comment: I am using windows 10 x64, and redis version 3.2.100. Intel i5 8thgen, 8gb ram, and 4gb dedicated graphics

Comment: First at all I get an error when inserting 1m values (guess the "batch" size is too big) so I reduced it to 500k. 

[i7 ubuntu] py: 1.9s, js: 0.7s

[i5 4th-gen win10] py: 4.3s, js: 1.2s

(bench scripts: https://gist.github.com/sui77/b1cee1da8582d5d97aa917a5347358eb https://gist.github.com/sui77/1d859e72fe2bc612b3747076decb95a5)

Just downloaded + run redis-2.4.5 windows binaries without any config changes.